# Will WPF work anywhere winforms work? (xp,vista, 7)

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am creating a windows application for users with xp, vista or 7 PCs.  I was wondering if WPF would work on all these computers, or should I play it safe and just use winforms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they will run ok if the computer has the correct .net framework installed.

It would be a good idea to redistribute the framwork with your application. Here is a topic in msdn about how to do it [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324733)

Comment: but I do not know the version of .net they are running :( The only information is that they are running newer updated XP

Comment: But you will get the same problem if you develop in winforms and compile using other framework (3.5, 4.0 etc) that are not installed in the client. So, winforms will not be safest than WPF.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Forms has been in .NET since .NET 1, with a few additions in .NET 2. WPF is available in .NET 3 – so, if someone has XP with .NET 2 installed, WPF won't work there.

Apart from that, you can of course install the appropriate .NET framework version on old machines as well. But the implication (WinForms works → WPF works) is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It will work on all of them, although you won't get the aero glass interface in XP.  Obviously, you will need a reasonably up-to-date .NET framework runtime installed on the target machine.

Answer (score 1):

WPF was added in .NET 3.0, so will run on any machine running 3.0 or a newer of the .NET Framework.  However, the rendering technologies differ dramatically between WPF and WinForms, so you may need to take that into account.  MSDN has a decent set of documents on WPF performance, some of which cover performance-related issues: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970683(v=VS.85).aspx.

Answer (score 1):

We use WPF applictaions for XP, Vista and win7 customers and it works fine on platforms.
If you can get the right framework on the machine it will run. So far we are using Version 3.51 and no problems so far.

Answer (score 1):

As other have mentioned, your dependency is on the ability to run the .net framework 3.0.  .net 3.0 is supported on the following platforms according to the link below.

> Software Requirements
>
> To install .NET Framework 3.0, you
> must have one of the following
> operating systems installed on the
> target computer:
>
> Microsoft Windows XP Home or Microsoft Windows XP Home Professional, with Service Pack 2 or later.
>
> Microsoft Windows Server 2003 family with Service Pack 1 or later.Service Pack 1 or later.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480198.aspx#netfx30_topic9